# awk FS with back slashes

Tags: awk, escape-characters

I use the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d`
which generates output like `./filename.1.out`

I pipe the find command output to `awk`. The goal is to split on either the literal `./` or `.`. I have it working using:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\\./)|(\\.)" } ; { print NF }'
```

In fact it works if I drop the first backslash in the first set of paren. Ex:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\./)|(\\.)" } ; { print NF }'
```

What I don't understand - and my question is why does it not work if I use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "(\./)|(\.)" } ; { print NF }'
```

By "not work" I mean NF returns with a number as if the second paren was a regex . character (to match any type of character). Maybe I'm answering my own question... but as I look at the commands/behavior it would appear that the initial backslash is being ignored. In fact, there was a warning escape sequence message saying that `\`. was being treated as plain '.'. But I didn't really understand what it was doing until I began printing NF.

And indeed... the awk doc for escape sequences (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html#Escape-Sequences) say:

> The backslash character itself is another character that cannot be included normally; you must write `\\` to put one backslash in the string or regexp.

So if I wanted to wring a regex to match a dollar sign then I would need `FS="\\$"`?

The post was originally to ask why it was happening. Then I *believe* I may have pieced things together. If I am wrong then please set me straight.

Comment: Your second case works by luck: de-escaped-with-warning `(\./|\\.)` means field delim is 'either any character and slash, or dot (by itself)'. It happens that in your input the only character that ever precedes slash is dot. Similarly `(\./|\.)` does indeed match any character (and every character) as a field delimiter. FYI you don't need the parentheses. For FS as a regex to match `$` yes you must escape. Note however that if FS is a single character it is NOT treated as a regex, just a character, so the single character `$` will also work.

Comment: Do you really want `-not -type d` rather than `-type f` ?

Comment: @symcbean: `-not -type d` does not mean `-type f`. Like not negative does not mean positive, it's can be zero.

Comment: @cuonglm: quite aware of that, just wondering why Gregg wants to parse device nodes and pipes.

Comment: @symcbean: I had not even considered that what I was doing (by using -not -type d) would include those things. Honestly, I'm not really sure what they are and should read up on them. But I think it is safe to say that using -type f is what I was really after. Thanks! Wish I could upvote comments.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: thanks. the whole single character thing is something that I missed the first time around while reading the awk manual. But as I was trying to figure out the problem I picked up on that because it bothered me how awk/gawk differentiated between regular strings and regular expressions - that's how. ;) I'll be playing with the paren soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FS` value was scanned twice, the first as a string value and the second as an ERE (See [Lexical Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_17)).

And also, POSIX did not specify the behavior of `\c` when `c` is not one of `"`, `/`, `\ddd` with `d` is one of octal digits, `\`, `a`, `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`. So you don't know whether string `\c` will be passed as `\c` or `c` to ERE.

`gawk`, `nawk`, and [Brian Kernighan's own version](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/index.html) give you `c`, while `mawk` give you `\c`:

```
$ for AWK in gawk mawk nawk bk-awk; do
  printf '<%s>\n' "$AWK"
  echo | "$AWK" -F '\.' '{print FS}'
done
<gawk>
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
.
<mawk>
\.
<nawk>
.
<bk-awk>
.
```

Because `\\` will always be recognized as `\`, then you will be safe with `\\c`:

```
$ for AWK in gawk mawk nawk bk-awk; do
printf '<%s>\n' "$AWK"; echo | "$AWK" -F '\\.' '{print FS}'
done
<gawk>
\.
<mawk>
\.
<nawk>
\.
<bk-awk>
\.
```

The string value of `\\c` will be `\c`, so using it as an ERE give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the links where I could read more about how the conversions are done. I'm really trying to understand why certain things work instead of just accepting that it works. :) It took me a while to mark as answered because I was trying to read everything you pointed me to - to see if it would answer a different question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564207/difference-between-variable-assignments). But it seems like the new problem I had was somewhat unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

`\x` becomes one character in a double-quoted string (just like in most shells and C) before it's regarded as a regex, so you do need to type `\\.` to construct `\.`.

Let's test that (you don't need the parentheses since the alternation operator `|` has the lowest precedence):

```
$ echo ./a.b.c | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\.|\./" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { print i ": " $i } }'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 
7:
```

The warning is telling you that the escape sequence in the string is superfluous. So FS is `.|./` and you're splitting on every character, yielding a bunch of empty fields.

Now with the doubled-up `\`:

```
$ echo ./a.b.c | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\.|\\./" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { print i ": " $i } }'
1: 
2: a
3: b
4: c
```

Comment: That's not always true. `mawk` is an exception.