# awking for command options from man page

Tags: awk, regular-expression, quoting, man

I am trying to auto-generate tab-completions for different commands. I am piping man pages for different commands into awk, then searching for command line options (eg. `-shortopt --long-option`) printing each on a separate line:

```
for (i=1;i<NF;i++){
    if(match("\<-[0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+\>", $i)){
        print $i
    }
}
```

For some reason this refuses to work. With single backslashes, awk warns about ignoring the escape sequence `\<`, then treats it as a literal `\\<`. If I double the backslashed, awk then refuses to actually match against the appropriate pattern (which works if I open the man page in vim, then run that pattern, so I think the pattern should be correct). The above code snippet lives in a file, then I invoke it with `man {section} {page} | awk -f find-options.awk`, so I think I can rule out issues with the command string being parsed multiple times by both bash and awk (as in [awk FS with back slashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264925/awk-fs-with-back-slashes)) as awk should be reading the script file directly.

Comment: You might get better results searching the *roff source markup

Comment: Yes, as roaima says, it would be _easier_ to parse the roff sources than to parse the generated manual. But there are a few competing roff macro sets for typesetting manuals, so a solution that parses roff sources would have to take Linux `man` sources _and_ `mandoc` sources into account (at least) to be generally useful.  When you parse _generated manuals_ (as in the question), you may want to take into account that the resulting text may use control sequences for doing highlighting and bold text etc.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are looking for as a result but as a Hint in order to use a word boundaries ability in awk, you could use a variable to define your regex then use that variable and find a match against of that like `man …| awk 'BEGIN{myRegex="\\<-[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+\\>";} {for(...) if(match($i, myRegex)) do_somehintg}'`

Comment: You have the match() arguments in the wrong order, assuming that first string is supposed to be your regexp. If so then you're also using a dynamic regexp `"..."` instead of a static regexp `/.../` and so need to double the escapes to account for 1 being consumed by the process of converting the string to a regexp. Also `\<` is gawk-only - are you using gawk?

Answer (score 0):

```
man ls | col -bx | nawk '
{
    for (ii=1;ii<=NF;ii++) {
        if ( match($ii,/^(-[a-zA-Z0-9]|--[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/) )
            opt[substr($ii,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
     }  
} 
END { for (oo in opt) printf("%s\n",oo)  } '
```

This should work in any "new" awk (`nawk`, `mawk`, `gawk`).

Things that were changed:

1. loop variable name, and off-by-one error
2. wrong order in `match()` arguments, as noted by Ed Morton
3. use `/.../` for literal regex, don't escape `+`, and remove incorrect use of `\<`  (it won't match because `-` is not in a "word", only letters, digits, underscores)¹
4. pipe though `col -b` to remove backspacing/overstriking
5. save all the observed options in an array to suppress duplicates on output

The escaping error observed arises from the wrong ordering of `match()` arguments, "<" in a literal string does not need to, and should not, be escaped. Only `\<` in a regex (with proper `/.../` delimiters) has special meaning. If  the regex is a literal "string" or in a variable, then you use `"\\<"` in the literal string in order to represent `\<` in the regex.

The [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) package has an feature which does something similar to your aim, its `_longopt` function invokes a command with `--help` in order to generate completion on the fly, ultimately using something like:

```
compgen -W "$( LC_ALL=C $COMMAND --help 2>&1 | \
  sed -ne 's/.*\(--[-A-Za-z0-9]\{1,\}=\{0,1\}\).*/\1/p' | sort -u )"
```

You might also find the implementation (perl) of [`help2man`](https://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/) instructive, this processes the output of "`command --help`" or equivalent to produce a minimal man page.

---

¹ the `\<` and `\>` *zero-width assertions* are non-POSIX and uncommon now, in PCRE `\b(?<=\W)` and `\b(?=\W)` are used. Support in `gawk` is a GNU-ism, though not documented as such. Solaris ERE matching also supports them, though its `awk` does not — there they can also match the beginning or end of a string, so work as intended (i.e. with `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E`).

They don't match start/end of string in GNU awk, but `/-\<[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+\>/` would work, having changed `\<-` to `-\<` to match following word characters.